Kubuntu 22.04 cant connect to wifi - configuring interface and auth loop
For some reason I can not connect co new wifi.
WHAT I DO
select "Domaci" wifi
set password (did it like milion times, I am sure it is correct)
WHAT HAPPENS
wifi starts at configuring interface
it last for few seconds and than "limited connectivity" pop up shows
than KUBUNTU asks again for password
THAT I TRIED
set password for every user - did not work
tried this KDE intermittent wifi problem "configuring interface"
forgot and reconfigure connection
restart NewtworkManager
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

This logs could be helpful
robert@robert-omen:~$ nmcli device status
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE                     CONNECTION      
wlo1             wifi      connecting (configuring)  Domaci          
br-2b08736651f6  bridge    connected (externally)    br-2b08736651f6 
lo               loopback  connected (externally)    lo              
docker0          bridge    connected (externally)    docker0         
p2p-dev-wlo1     wifi-p2p  disconnected              --              
eno1             ethernet  unavailable               --              
robert@robert-omen:~$ nmcli device status
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE                             CONNECTION      
wlo1             wifi      connecting (need authentication)  Domaci          
br-2b08736651f6  bridge    connected (externally)            br-2b08736651f6 
lo               loopback  connected (externally)            lo              
docker0          bridge    connected (externally)            docker0         
p2p-dev-wlo1     wifi-p2p  disconnected                      --              
eno1             ethernet  unavailable     

robert@robert-omen:~$ journalctl -xe
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen avahi-daemon[1172]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::7ddd:ec97:26b7:3060 on wlo1.
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen avahi-daemon[1172]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::7ddd:ec97:26b7:3060.
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.8842] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen avahi-daemon[1172]: Interface wlo1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.8842] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.8842] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed no lease
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen wpa_supplicant[1247]: wlo1: PMKSA-CACHE-REMOVED 36:1b:fe:70:81:3a 0
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen avahi-daemon[1172]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.203.92 on wlo1.
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen avahi-daemon[1172]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv4 with address 192.168.203.92.
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen systemd-resolved[904]: wlo1: Bus client set default route setting: no
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen systemd-resolved[904]: wlo1: Bus client reset DNS server list.
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen avahi-daemon[1172]: Interface wlo1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9719] device (wlo1): Activation: starting connection 'Domaci' (b5577c24-3c8f-4b44-bec7-c14c565db941)
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9730] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9730] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9740] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9743] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9747] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9752] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Domaci' has security, but secrets are required.
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9752] device (wlo1): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9755] sup-iface[81573d5746fd0db7,1,wlo1]: wps: type pbc start...
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9769] device (wlo1): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9773] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9777] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Domaci' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9778] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Domaci'
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9779] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9779] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9779] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807891.9779] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen wpa_supplicant[1247]: wlo1: WPS-CANCEL
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen kded5[2949]: "Object does not exist at path “/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5”"
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen kdeconnectd[3221]: "Object does not exist at path “/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5”"
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen DiscoverNotifier[3263]: "Object does not exist at path “/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5”"
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen kded5[2949]: org.kde.plasma.nm.kded: Unhandled active connection state change:  1
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen kded5[2949]: kf.networkmanagerqt: void NetworkManager::ConnectionPrivate::onPropertiesChanged(const QVariantMap&) Unhandled property "VersionId"
srp 04 23:44:51 robert-omen plasmashell[3020]: kf.networkmanagerqt: void NetworkManager::ConnectionPrivate::onPropertiesChanged(const QVariantMap&) Unhandled property "VersionId"
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen plasmashell[3020]: Could not find the Plasmoid for Plasma::FrameSvgItem(0x563844193ce0) QQmlContext(0x5638419a9980) QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/global/Gl>
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen plasmashell[3020]: Could not find the Plasmoid for Plasma::FrameSvgItem(0x563844193ce0) QQmlContext(0x5638419a9980) QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/global/Gl>
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen wpa_supplicant[1247]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with 40:5f:7d:0f:ba:b6 (SSID='Domaci' freq=2412 MHz)
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen kernel: wlo1: authenticate with 40:5f:7d:0f:ba:b6 (local address=4c:d5:77:87:be:7f)
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen kernel: wlo1: send auth to 40:5f:7d:0f:ba:b6 (try 1/3)
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807892.3158] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807892.3159] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen wpa_supplicant[1247]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 40:5f:7d:0f:ba:b6 (SSID='Domaci' freq=2412 MHz)
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen kernel: wlo1: authenticated
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807892.3258] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807892.3259] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen kernel: wlo1: associate with 40:5f:7d:0f:ba:b6 (try 1/3)
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen kernel: wlo1: associate with 40:5f:7d:0f:ba:b6 (try 2/3)
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen kernel: wlo1: associate with 40:5f:7d:0f:ba:b6 (try 3/3)
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen kernel: wlo1: association with 40:5f:7d:0f:ba:b6 timed out
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807892.7002] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807892.7003] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807892.8509] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
srp 04 23:44:52 robert-omen NetworkManager[1243]: <info>  [1722807892.8510] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
srp 04 23:44:53 robert-omen plasmashell[3020]: file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/plasma/extras/PlaceholderMessage.qml:238:5: QML Heading: Binding loop detected for property "verticalAlignment"

NOTE
There are several Android and Windows devices connected to this wifi

These commands need to start with sudo (apt update && apt upgrade)
